# Why is the data in this ExtJS grid not showing?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've isolated the checkbox grid from [this example of ExtJS grids](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/grid-plugins.js) into the following code.

It shows the grid with the headers but not the data:

[image]

Firebug shows no Javascript errors.

**What do I have to do to get the dummy data to show in the grid?**

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.QuickTips.init();

    var xg = Ext.grid;

    var reader = new Ext.data.ArrayReader({}, [
        {name: 'company'},
        {name: 'price', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'change', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'pctChange', type: 'float'},
        {name: 'lastChange', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j h:ia'},
        {name: 'industry'},
        {name: 'desc'}
    ]);

    var sm = new xg.CheckboxSelectionModel();

    var grid2 = new xg.GridPanel({
        store: new Ext.data.Store({
            reader: reader,
            data: xg.dummyData
        }),
        cm: new xg.ColumnModel({
            defaults: {
                width: 120,
                sortable: true
            },
            columns: [
                sm,
                {id:'company',header: "Company", width: 200, dataIndex: 'company'},
                {header: "Price", renderer: Ext.util.Format.usMoney, dataIndex: 'price'},
                {header: "Change", dataIndex: 'change'},
                {header: "% Change", dataIndex: 'pctChange'},
                {header: "Last Updated", width: 135, renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), dataIndex: 'lastChange'}
            ]
        }),
        sm: sm,
        columnLines: true,
        width:800,
        height:300,
        frame:true,
        title:'Framed with Checkbox Selection and Horizontal Scrolling',
        iconCls:'icon-grid',
        renderTo: document.body
    });

    Ext.grid.dummyData = [
        ['3m Co',71.72,0.02,0.03,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['Alcoa Inc',29.01,0.42,1.47,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['Altria Group Inc',83.81,0.28,0.34,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['American Express Company',52.55,0.01,0.02,'9/1 12:00am', 'Finance'],
        ['American International Group, Inc.',64.13,0.31,0.49,'9/1 12:00am', 'Services'],
        ['AT&T Inc.',31.61,-0.48,-1.54,'9/1 12:00am', 'Services'],
        ['Boeing Co.',75.43,0.53,0.71,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['Caterpillar Inc.',67.27,0.92,1.39,'9/1 12:00am', 'Services'],
        ['Citigroup, Inc.',49.37,0.02,0.04,'9/1 12:00am', 'Finance'],
        ['E.I. du Pont de Nemours and Company',40.48,0.51,1.28,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['Exxon Mobil Corp',68.1,-0.43,-0.64,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['General Electric Company',34.14,-0.08,-0.23,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['General Motors Corporation',30.27,1.09,3.74,'9/1 12:00am', 'Automotive'],
        ['Hewlett-Packard Co.',36.53,-0.03,-0.08,'9/1 12:00am', 'Computer'],
        ['Honeywell Intl Inc',38.77,0.05,0.13,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['Intel Corporation',19.88,0.31,1.58,'9/1 12:00am', 'Computer'],
        ['International Business Machines',81.41,0.44,0.54,'9/1 12:00am', 'Computer'],
        ['Johnson & Johnson',64.72,0.06,0.09,'9/1 12:00am', 'Medical'],
        ['JP Morgan & Chase & Co',45.73,0.07,0.15,'9/1 12:00am', 'Finance'],
        ['McDonald\'s Corporation',36.76,0.86,2.40,'9/1 12:00am', 'Food'],
        ['Merck & Co., Inc.',40.96,0.41,1.01,'9/1 12:00am', 'Medical'],
        ['Microsoft Corporation',25.84,0.14,0.54,'9/1 12:00am', 'Computer'],
        ['Pfizer Inc',27.96,0.4,1.45,'9/1 12:00am', 'Services', 'Medical'],
        ['The Coca-Cola Company',45.07,0.26,0.58,'9/1 12:00am', 'Food'],
        ['The Home Depot, Inc.',34.64,0.35,1.02,'9/1 12:00am', 'Retail'],
        ['The Procter & Gamble Company',61.91,0.01,0.02,'9/1 12:00am', 'Manufacturing'],
        ['United Technologies Corporation',63.26,0.55,0.88,'9/1 12:00am', 'Computer'],
        ['Verizon Communications',35.57,0.39,1.11,'9/1 12:00am', 'Services'],
        ['Wal-Mart Stores, Inc.',45.45,0.73,1.63,'9/1 12:00am', 'Retail'],
        ['Walt Disney Company (The) (Holding Company)',29.89,0.24,0.81,'9/1 12:00am', 'Services']
    ];

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it: the `Ext.grid.dummyData` block just has to be defined outside the `Ext.onReady(function(){`
 block.